# Ruby Code Highlight in Lyx / Latex

Tags: lyx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby highlighter for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17365/ruby-highlighter-for-latex)

I am working on a tutorials document / short book and I was wondering if there is a way to use Ruby colour code highlight within Lyx ? I have google and tried several approaches but the best I could find was this
http://www.tux-crazy.com/2011/11/tips-to-get-you-started-with-lyx-part-2.html and it just make some keywords highlighted in bold or 1 colour - hardly ideal for tutorials.

Is syntax highlighting for Ruby possible in an efficient and eye candy way on lyx ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what do you exactly expect from the result? Also have a look at the documentation for the [listing package](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) which offers supports Ruby and is highly customisable. (Follow the link in the comment above for a example).